# Issue in Generating TestNG.xml File

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

i try to Generate TestNG.xml through java code but it is working when i run it as java application, but it is not generating the XML File Seperately.May i know Why, Code Works Fine But can't able to Generate the Xml File Seperatly .

My Code :

```
package Testcases;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.testng.TestListenerAdapter;
import org.testng.TestNG;
import org.testng.xml.XmlClass;
import org.testng.xml.XmlSuite;
import org.testng.xml.XmlTest;

public class GenerateTestng
{
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void runTestNGTest() {

        //Create an instance on TestNG
         TestNG myTestNG = new TestNG();

        //Create an instance of XML Suite and assign a name for it.
         XmlSuite mySuite = new XmlSuite();
         mySuite.setName("MySuite");

        //Create an instance of XmlTest and assign a name for it.
         XmlTest myTest = new XmlTest(mySuite);
         myTest.setName("Wepaythemaxx");


        //Create a list which can contain the classes that you want to run.
         List<XmlClass> myClasses = new ArrayList<XmlClass> ();
         myClasses.add(new XmlClass("Testcases.FinalTest"));

        //Assign that to the XmlTest Object created earlier.
         myTest.setXmlClasses(myClasses);

        //Create a list of XmlTests and add the Xmltest you created earlier to it.
         List<XmlTest> myTests = new ArrayList<XmlTest>();
         myTests.add(myTest);

        //add the list of tests to your Suite.
         mySuite.setTests(myTests);

        //Add the suite to the list of suites.
         List<XmlSuite> mySuites = new ArrayList<XmlSuite>();
         mySuites.add(mySuite);

        //Set the list of Suites to the testNG object you created earlier.
         myTestNG.setXmlSuites(mySuites);

         TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
         myTestNG.addListener(tla);

        //invoke run() - this will run your class.
         myTestNG.run();
        }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        GenerateTestng dt = new GenerateTestng();
         dt.runTestNGTest();
    }

}
```

i have attached my code above, please verify, Where i done mistake i can't figure it out.

Comment: you wish to create also the xml file in the system?

Comment: i Thought, by creating this java file, Testng.xml will be generated in my project. That is what my doubt @Infern0

Comment: you have to create it with additional code. use FileWriter

Comment: okay, thanks, let me do a research for it.if you know you can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created this method that will save the file:

```
public void createXmlFile(String saveFilePath, XmlSuite suiteName) {
    File file = new File(saveFilePath);
    FileWriter writer = null;
    try {
        writer = new FileWriter(file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        writer.write(suiteName.toXml());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(suiteName.toXml());
    try {
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Where

- saveFilePath = the path where the file will be saved e.g. '.testNGxml.xml'
- suiteName = your suite name, in your case mySuite

Comment: Awesome Man, it Generated the XML. Whoooooo!

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse has a TestNG extension that creates the xml on its own. You can then edit the xml to change the order the tests are run on(so that you can create mock data, edit said data and delete it without getting an error for example).

I am sure most IDEs have similar approaches.

Any reason you are not using an IDE?.

Comment: I Know the that one, what you are saying, but i trying can we create the testng.xml  by using java code or not. @user2304843